# How to identify Android buttons and objects with Appium Inspector

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

I'm trying to identify different button on a PDA\telephone using Appium Inspector. The problem that I have is that I have 12 buttons on the menu and they all have the same resource ID. At this point in time I'm using the Xpath to identify some of the button have almost the same name so I can't differentiate between them. The developer has put this in but I can't get access to it via Appium Inspector.

menu_btnLivraisons.setTag("menu_btnLivraisons");

I now have access to the source code. How can I add some identifier that will enable me to identify the objects that won't break the application?

Thanks in advance!